# Ticker for a column using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to implement a ticker for a column. However the ticker is working only in the first row and not on the 2nd row onwards. Can someone help me understand on where I'm wrong?

JS Code to buld the table:

```
tr.append("<td id='time_ticker'>" + data[i].priority + "</td>");
```

Js code to start the ticker:

```
function minsTick() {
 var existing_priority = document.getElementById('time_ticker').innerHTML;
 var tmp = existing_priority.split(" ");
 var priority_time = tmp[0];
 var unit = tmp[1];
 var new_priority = priority_time - 1;
 if (unit === "Mins") {
  document.getElementById('time_ticker').innerHTML = new_priority + " " + unit;
 } 
}
```

Thanks is advance.

Comment: KEEP the data in a variable! Dont put it into the DOM and parse it from there. Its slow && !bugprove

Comment: It looks like you are setting the same id in loop. Do not do it. IDs must be unique within the document.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that your first code will duplicate the 'time_ticker' id, and js is expecting the ids to be unique in page .Try:

```
tr.append("<td class='time_ticker'>" + data[i].priority + "</td>");
```

and

```
function minsTick() {
 var existing_priority = document.getElementById('time_ticker').innerHTML;
 var tmp = existing_priority.split(" ");
 var priority_time = tmp[0];
 var unit = tmp[1];
 var new_priority = priority_time - 1;
 if (unit === "Mins") {
  document.getElementsByClassName('time_ticker').innerHTML = new_priority + " " + unit;
 } 
}
```